# C# Using WebBrowser class to find open IE page and read the HTML

Tags: c#

I am trying to use the WebBrowser class in C# to find an already opened IE instance and set that open page to be handled by my WebBrowser wb variable. I know several ways of searching already open IE pages using other classes and libraries and I also know how to open the page from within WebBrowser and proceed that way but I was hoping that WebBrowser might have someway of capturing an already opened IE instance.

I have searched but cannot find the answer to this, is there no way from within this class? Thank you.

Comment: I don't believe WebBrowser supports this.  It's running it's own IE process in the background.  Might not even be the same IE version that the user is browsing with.

Comment: You might want to look at using Selenium WebDriver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `WebBrowser` class is not capable to search for opened IE instances. It is designed to host its own instance of IE.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. Is there another class perhaps that can search for an already open IE instance and invoke "clicks" like the invokemember method in WebBrowser? Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Below, I've posted a piece of an app I had to find an IE instance with a certain URL and Kill it.  I know you said you wanted to use WebBrowswer, but this works... Of course, you'll need to import SHDocVw

```
        For Each ieWindow As InternetExplorer In interfaceWindows
            If ieWindow.LocationURL.Contains("myweburl.com") Then
                Dim ieWinHandle As IntPtr = New IntPtr(ieWindow.HWND)
                Console.WriteLine(ieWinHandle.ToString)
                ieWindow.Quit()
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: If you wanted to invoke clicks on this, you would need to use a reference t the handle.  Also, the InternetExplorer class has quite a few usefull properties and methods.